# array object's variable to equal value returned from a function using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

as you'll see in a sec, im new to angular. i want each object in the users array to have a value (difference) which is a result returned from a function calculating the difference between the user's score to top score.
* in my code harry will have difference of 1 for example.
how can i achieve that?

HTML:

```
<body>
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Score</td>
        <td>Difference</td>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: '-score'">
            <td >{{user.name}}</td>
            <td >{{user.score}}</td>
            <td>{{user.difference}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

myApp.controller ('firstCtrl', function($scope, PersonService){

    $scope.users = PersonService.list();

    $scope.difference = function (id) {
        PersonService.difference(id);
    }
})

myApp.service('PersonService',function(){

    var uid = 1;
    var users = [{
        id: 0,
        'name': 'John',
        'score': '46',
        'difference': 'diff from top'
    },{
        id: 0,
        'name': 'Harry',
        'score': '45',
        'difference': 'diff from top'
    },{
        id: 0,
        'name': 'Sam',
        'score': '43',
        'difference': 'diff from top'
    }];

    //simply returns the contacts list
    this.list = function () {
        return users;
    }

    this.difference = function(id){
        for (i in users) {
            if (users[i].id == id) {
                return (Math.max.apply(Math, users.score) - users[i].score);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'd argue this is a plain Javascript question, AngularJS is in no way related to your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, to improve efficiently, you only want to get the max score once.

So introduce a variable to store this value instead of computing it over and over again for each user:

```
var maxScore = getMaxScore(); // I leave the implementation to you as you seem to know how to do this
```

Second, using the JavaScript map function, append the new attribute to each element on the array:

```
users = users.map(function(user) { 
    return user.diff = maxScore - user.score;
});
```

Now you have the users array with the additional diff attribute for every user.

---

If you only need the difference for presentation on the HTML, another, more "Angularish" way of doing it, would be to add the maxScore to the scope:

```
$scope.maxScore = getMaxScore();
```

And on the HTML template, include the difference as a dynamically calculated value:

```
<td>{{maxScore - user.score}}</td>
```